# put label in frame without class etc

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

How can I get the label in this simple frame? I tried to make the label go to the frame but then I only see the label and the frame disappears.

Notice here that I want 2 different sizes. The root.geometry("200x200") which is gray. I also am putting a Frame in the root of 100w x 100h. Run the code, I can see both color areas great. But my label does not appear, in the Frame darkgray area. Which is my problem.

```
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("basicGUI")
root.configure(background="gray")

frame = Frame(width=100, height=100,
              bg="darkgray")
frame.pack()

mylabel=Label(text="anyWord")
mylabel.pack()

"""
# darkgray frame disappears
mylabel=Label(frame, text="anyWord")
mylabel.pack(side = LEFT)
"""

mainloop()
```

Comment: Can you clarify what your desired output is? I'm looking at your current output and not clear on what exactly you want.

Comment: You are not putting your label into the frame. Specify its parent when creating your label. `mylabel = Label(frame, text = ..)`

Comment: the .py shows a darkgray 100w x 100h darkgray Frame which is good. What I need is the label to go into the darkgray Frame.  What I get is the label under the darkgray Frame area, which is my 200w x 200h root area. I need the label in the darkgray Frame area.

Comment: @rasPi2bSarah That's why you should specify its parent(at where that widget should be placed). Have you tried what I wrote on above comment?

Comment: @Lafexlos I tried your suggestion before I posted. That's what I thought also but ... that didn't work. I've tried many ways, all with failure of course. So I posted here to ask someone stronger than us.

Comment: @rasPi2bSarah If you use `mylabel=Label(frame,..)`, your label _is_ in the frame. It's just, your frame changes its size for label and seems like it disappears. Try disabling frame's propagation as well.  `frame.pack_propagate(0)`

Comment: notice in my code, I have 2 different color areas. One is the root GUI which is 200w x 200h. The other is Frame area which is darkgray 100w x 100h which should always be dark gray. How do I get the label in the Frame darkgray 100w x 100h area???

Comment: @Lafexlos frame.pack_propagate(0) does nothing to help. I should not be losing the darkgray Frame area.

Comment: You are either not understanding what I am saying or not making clear what you want. If you want a frame that doesn't shrink, you _must_ disable propagation. Else, it will shrink to fit label's size. There is no mid-point for this. It shrinks or not. That's it.

Comment: @Lafexlos root.geometry("200x200") does not shrink, and it remains gray background. Frame 100w x 100h also does not shrink and remains darkgray background. Which is what I am after. The problem is placing the label in the Frame darkgray area.

Comment: @rasPi2bSarah Have you even tried what I've said? Please change `mylabel=Label(text="anyWord")` to `mylabel=Label(frame, text="anyWord")` and add `frame.pack_propagate(0)` before `frame.pack()`.

Comment: @Lafexlos Wow ... exactly what I wanted. Your the BOMB for sure. Thanks for stayin with me on this. I was changing frame.pack() not adding frame.pack_propate(0)

Comment: @Lafexlos: `pack_propagate(0)` is almost never the right answer. It might be a quick fix for this problem, but I think if we understood the _real_ problem, that wouldn't be the solution.

Comment: I don't understand the question. When I run the code as-is, the label _does_ appear in the dark gray area, right below the text. How is that different from what you really want? Do you want the label _above_ the inner gray rectangle? Did you try packing the label with `side=TOP` _before_ packing the gray rectangle?

Comment: @Bryan Oakley ... When looking for python books, I found "Python for Advanced Programmers" They taught never to use Class way of writing programs. I didn't buy the book, but I do remember reading that bit on the cover.

Comment: @rasPi2bSarah: that book has bad advice. It's good you didn't buy it. While it's certainly possible to make large GUIs without using classes, using classes makes the task easier. I don't know what any of that has to do with this question, though.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley ... where would I put `side=TOP` ? I'm using linux IDLE python 2.7.11. I had to add frame.pack_propagate(0) above frame.pack() to get it to work as I want.

Comment: @Bryan Oakley ... because you wrote "is almost never the solution ..."

Comment: you put it where you current have `side=LEFT`.

Comment: how can I make code pieces of my sentence in gray like you guys do?

Comment: The problem here is that you aren't describing your true requirements. You want the label "in the dark gray area". That could mean above the other rectangle, below it, to the left, to the right, etc. Why do you need an empty rectangle? While you can use `pack_propagate(0)` to help you _in this very specific case_, as soon as you try making a real GUI with other widgets, you'll have problems.  If you can precisely describe what you really need, there is likely a very simple solution. For example, packing the label before the other frame, or  using `grid` instead of `pack`, etc.

Comment: There are 2 areas. gray and darkgray. Today's help got my label in the darkgray area. Now I will learn grid etc. I work hard at learning python everyday. I'm 14yo with only a rasPy2B. I appreciate the help you forum folks give me very much. My school does not teach programming. So i'm stuck trying to pick it up the hard way.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Lafexlos, a one line addition solved my problem.

```
from Tkinter import *

root=Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
root.title("basicGUI")
root.configure(background="gray")

frame = Frame(width=100, height=100,
              bg="darkgray")

frame.pack_propagate(0) #adding line solves problem
frame.pack()

mylabel1=Label(frame, text="anyWord")
mylabel1.pack(side = TOP)

mainloop()
```